# kendo UI combobox paging issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to use combobox control that may return huge data even after filtration so I need to use something like paging to minimize the displayed data.

Does kendo combobox has paging features,if not are there any work around?

Note : I use the MVC razor version

Answer (score 1):

The Kendo ComboBox doesn't support paging.